# Global Collections

Tags: excel, vba

I have a collection that I have declared at the top of a module as

`Public myCol as new Collection`

I am using a `Sub` to populate the collection, however this does not write to the global collection and upon exiting the `Sub` the contents are gone.

I'm assuming the items, since created in the sub, only have local scope.

How can I use a routine or function to populate the collection globally?

I would prefer to not have to pass objects if possible as I am populating multiple global collections in the single subroutine.

Comment: You are assuming wrong... Please, edit your code and **show us the code in discussion**. If you **also locally declared `Dim myCol` (If "created in the sub" means that), it will remain a local variable**.  If this is your problem, you should **eliminate it from the respective `Sub` declarations**. Excel accepts it, but changes its scope. Only in such a situation. If not, please show us the code to try understanding more.

Comment: At the top of the module, you will declare `Public myCol As Collection` without `New`. In a `Sub` you could then use something like `If myCol is Nothing Then Set myCol = New Collection` before adding items to it.

Comment: When passing an object as a parameter, VBA  passes an address related to the object.  If you pass ByRef, you get the actual address of the object, if you pass ByVal you get a pointer to the address of the object.  The difference between byRef and ByVal for objects can be seen if you assign a new object to the parameter.  With byRef, you will replace the original object so anything referencing the object will now also reference the new object.  With byVal, the pointer will be changed to reflect the new object, anything referencing the original object will still referenc the original object.

Answer (score 3):

Create a Standard module to hold your public objects and expose them via properties. The property getter can then check if the object has been initialized before returning it.

See an example:

```
Private m_collection As VBA.Collection

Public Property Get GlobalCollection() As VBA.Collection
    If m_collection Is Nothing Then Set m_collection = New VBA.Collection
    Set GlobalCollection = m_collection
End Property
```

To call it:

```
YourModuleName.GlobalCollection.Add "Something"
```

or

```
GlobalCollection.Add "Something"
```

Comment: Could  use a predeclared singleton/ static class with the Class_Initialize creating the global object etc.